# 2D Array, how to find each columns highest value owner

Tags: java, arrays

I have a homework in which i need to create 2D array with buyers and products. Every product and buyer has its number for example [buyer1] [product1], [buyer1] [product2], [buyer1] [product3] etc. i need to find most expensive product from every column and who has bought it. I have found a way which prints most expensive product but i don't know how to declare the buyer for those products

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    float arrayPrices[][];
    String arrayNames[];

    int c = 3;
    int n = 3;

    arrayNames = new String[c];

    arrayNames [0] = "John";       
    arrayNames [1] = "Jake";    
    arrayNames [2] = "Lucy";         

    arrayPrices = new float[c][n];
    arrayPrices [0][0] = 12;
    arrayPrices [0][1] = 2;
    arrayPrices [0][2] = 21;

    arrayPrices [1][0] = 132;
    arrayPrices [1][1] = 12;
    arrayPrices [1][2] = 1112;

    arrayPrices [2][0] = 32;
    arrayPrices [2][1] = 452;
    arrayPrices [2][2] = 125;


    for(int i = 0;i<c;i++){

    }

    for(int i = 0;i<c;i++){
         for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){

        }   

    }       

    String BuyerName;
    float MaxPrice = 0.0f;

    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
    BuyerName = arrayNames[i];
        for(int j = 0;j<c;j++){
            if(MaxPrice < arrayPrices[j][i] || MaxPrice == arrayPrices[j][i]){
                MaxPrice = arrayPrices[j][i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i + " product highest price was " + MaxPrice + "Buyer was: " + BuyerName );
        MaxPrice = 0.0f;
    }   

}
```

}

Comment: Please stick to **naming conventions**. Class names start with CamelCase, variable and method names with a lowercase letter. So your `BuyerName` and `MaxPrice` should be named `buyerName` and `maxPrice`. As you see SO highlights them as if they where classes which makes reading harder for others.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
    String BuyerName;
    float MaxPrice = 0.0f;

    int mostExpensiveBuyer =-1;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
        BuyerName = arrayNames[i];
        for(int j = 0;j<c;j++){
            if(MaxPrice < arrayPrices[j][i] || MaxPrice == arrayPrices[j][i]){
                MaxPrice = arrayPrices[j][i];
                mostExpensiveBuyer = j;
            }
        }

        MaxPrice = 0.0f;
    }
    System.out.println("Buyer with the most expensive product is " + arrayNames[mostExpensiveBuyer]);
```

Comment: What have you changed? Why does this solve the issue? Can you provide an explanation please?

Comment: I use mostExpensivebuyer as a place holder for the index of the most expensive buyer so far as the for loop doing its job.